# Creating a diagonal border-left With css

Tags: css, styles, border

I am trying to create a diagonal border in this shape using some functions in CSS.

Is there a function in CSS: to create something like

[This is the shape i had already create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7WEE.png)

[This is a example how i want to transform it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9WxW.png)

a function or the code to reach something like this
[Wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8nyo.png)

Comment: if you want help.  you should post code examples here.  externally linked examples are unfavorable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're new to css you can try it using border-radius. It's fairly easy to shape elements but it's less customizable. In your case you can try "border-bottom-left-radius: 210px". Play around with the px value until you get what you need.

If you want full control over your shape you should use clip-path. More on how clip-path works here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path